# C Program: newbie confusion on working with character string arrays

Tags: c

I'm getting confused working with character string arrays. I'm trying to fill 2 arrays in a for loop. Within each array, all elements are the same.

To conserve memory, for `array_person_name` I attempt to simply copy the pointer to the string stored by `person_name`. For `array_param`, the string that it stores the pointer to is always 2 characters long (e.g. "bt") plus the null termination character , and here I also attempt to conserve memory by storing the pointer to "bt" in `array_param`.

Since the number of array elements, `arraysize`, is downloaded from a database when the program runs, I use malloc to allocate memory. Since my OS is 64 bit (Linux x86-64), I allocate 8 bytes for each of `arraysize` pointers. Although not shown, I free these two arrays at the end of the program.

```
int kk, arraysize;
char person_name[101] = ""; 
char * array_person_name;
char * array_param; 
...
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", 100);
arraysize = <this value is downloaded from database>;
...
array_person_name = malloc( 8 * arraysize ); /* 8 is for 64b OS */
array_param = malloc( 8 * arraysize ); 
for (kk = 0; kk < arraysize; kk++) {
    array_person_name[kk] = &person_name;
    array_param[kk] = &"bt";
}

/* test results by printing to screen */
printf("Here is array_person_name[0]: %s\n", array_person_name[0]);
printf("here is array_param[0]: %s\n", array_param[0]);
```

The compiler returns the warnings: `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast` on the two lines inside the for loop.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't "guess" the size of the pointers but use `sizeof(char *)`

Comment: If you really want to use `strncpy()` and zero-fill the tail end of your `person_name` array (again, because the initializer also zero-filled it), then use: `strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", sizeof(person_name));`. In general, using `sizeof()` helps. You do need to be cautious about whether you have an array name or just a pointer. `sizeof(array)` gives the size of the array, but `sizeof(pointer)` gives the size of a pointer, not the size of the array. Function arguments are pointers, not arrays. Be cautious about using `sizeof()` on function arguments, and pass arrays sizes with strings.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I included the `100` in strncpy to avoid potential errors if more than 100 characters are copied (I'm not trying to pad with spaces). My intent is to simply copy `John Smith` into `person_name`, along with a null character automatically included by the compiler. I'm not sure if your comment impacts this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want each item in `array_person_name` and `array_param` to be a pointer to `person_name`/"bt", you want a `char **`:

```
char **array_person_name;

array_person_name = malloc(arraysize * sizeof(*array_person_name));

for (int i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
    array_person_name[i] = person_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry, what should I use for malloc-ing `array_param`? Can I do , for example, `sizeof(*"bt")`?

Comment: You almost always want `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * item_count);`

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a pointer to array person_name to character defined by array_person_name[kk].  What you probably meant to do was to define array_person_name as a char** type.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be assuming 8 bytes because it's 64 bit. You should leave that part to C and use `sizeof()` operator.